# What is the necessity of “Prototyping Shield” for an arduino UNO R3?

Tags: arduino-uno, shields

I just want to learn arduino and make some small projects.But in beginner starter kit there's a part named Prototyping Shield .Is it necessary or will it help me?

Answer (score 1):

The prototyping shield can be used to build your own circuits up in a more permanent form which can be plugged direct into the Arduino.

You can think of it as a blank canvass on which you can paint your own shield design.